# Getting a Dodecahedron Graph to work in Manipulate

Tags: graphics, manipulate, graphs-and-networks

Right now I am currently using a grid graph for a "shortest path model", but ideally, I would like the shortest path model to work on a pentakis dodecahedron or rhombic triacontahedron. I will say I am not proficient in Mathematica at all so sorry if this is bad coding!

[image]

I am trying to make a model of this Pentakis Dodecahedral Graph (or something similar), but I cannot get it to work (I am not sure what I have to change to let it highlight the correct path, put vertices labels on the dodecahedron, and get it to be manipulated)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please put your code in copy-pasteable format rather than as an image. This also makes it much easier for people to test your code and to provide help

Comment: Use `GraphData["PentakisDodecahedralGraph"]` and *not* `GraphData["PentakisDodecahedralGraph", "Imag3D"]`. The latter is an image, not a graph.  But it's not very clear what it is *that you tried and did not work*.

Comment: If you just want it in 3D (with a force-directed layout), you can do `Graph3D@EdgeList@GraphData["PentakisDodecahedralGraph"]`. The force directed layout would recover the polyhedron's coordinates with good approximation. If you want the exact ones, you can convert a mesh to a graph with the [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) as `IGMeshGraph@
 PolyhedronData["PentakisDodecahedron", "BoundaryMeshRegion"]`. The problem is, I don't really understand what the question is, or what the *specific* difficulty was in replacing the GridGraph in your code.

Comment: @Szabolcs My apologies for being unclear, this is my first time using Stack exchange as well. I was having an issue putting the 3D image of the Pentakis Dodecahedral into my Qsat value, it was only working for the grid graph I was using before and the Dodecahedral was getting an error. Your first suggestion (Graph3D@EdgeList@GraphData) worked, however, so thank you very much! Do you know how to add labeled vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of polyhedron graphs available in Mathematica. You can list them up with:

```
PolyhedronData[]
```

The graph in your question you can get like:

```
dodecahedron = PolyhedronData["PentakisDodecahedron", "Skeleton"]
```

then (e.q.):

```
path = FindShortestPath[dodecahedron, 7, 20]
```

and

```
HighlightGraph[dodecahedron, PathGraph@path]
```

delivers:

[image]

Comment: This is what I am looking for thank you! Do you know how to make it 3D?

Comment: With this I am also having trouble labeling the vertices.